# Building iOS owncloud

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, owncloud

I'm trying to compile Owncloud client for iOS on XCode and I'm completely new with developing apps for mac.
I forked the project from Github, loaded it in XCode 6.3 and tried building it but I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OCCommunication", referenced from:
__TMaCS0150CCommunication in Managers.o
ld: symbols(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I still haven't change a comma in the code, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a framework.

Comment: Mm.. ok this is useful, but I have not idea on what's missing. 
I'll try and post back. Thanks trojanfoe

Comment: @Robbè:Hai have you solved this error?I am facing the same one now

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the exact issue you face but if you only forked and cloned the repo, that's not enough. Setup.md says the following:
Inside the folder ios:
Init the library submodule: "git submodule init"
Update the library submodule: "git submodule update".

So after cloning you need to:

```
cd ios
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Then you're good to go. At least that's what worked for me.
For reference: https://github.com/owncloud/ios/blob/master/SETUP.md